# Can I check if an object is comparable to some other type?

Tags: c#, .net, comparable, icomparable

I'd like to write some code like this:

```
if (obj.IsComparableTo(integer))
    Console.Write("successed");
```

Is this possible? If not, is there an alternative way of determining this?

Comment: @Marc Gravell:I have to check cmb.Tag is there some more optimum way?

Comment: what do you mean by `cmb.Tag` here?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

i've found it :

```
        public bool isComparable<t>(object o)
        {
            try
            {
                object r = (t)o;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

to use it:

```
if (isComparable<int>(32).ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("success");
else
    Console.WriteLine("fail");
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you mean by comparable, maybe:

```
var comparable = obj as IComparable<int>;
if(comparable != null) Console.Write("successed");
```

However, this only accounts for the interface, which would be rare. Most implicit conversions will be harder to check for. If you add more context, maybe a more appropriate solution will be easier to spot.

Comment: var comparable = combo1.tag as IComparable<int>;
if(comparable != null) Console.Write("successed"); doesnt work for me

Comment: @Moshen - well, given that you haven't told us what `obj` is, or what scenarios you need to cover by "comparable"...

Answer (score 1):

You object has to implement the interface `IComparable<int>`

```
public class Foo : IComparable<int>
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to compare two different types of objects unless they implement the `IComparable` interface.